# Align tikzfigure left

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, horizontal-alignment, align, minipage

I am creating a frame in beamer with two minipages, one of whom has a tikzpicture and the other bullet points. I'd love the Tikzfigure to be left aligned below the heading, but the other questions I've seen on alignment only deal with text.

How to align the whole Tikzfigure to the left of the minipage?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\textbf{Stuff}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.045]
            \node [right] at (34, 50) {\scriptsize stuff 1};
            \node [right] at (34, 107) {\scriptsize  stuff 2};
            \node [right] at (34, 120) {\scriptsize stuff 3};
            
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (30,114) --  (30,126.5);
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (30,100) --  (30,114);
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (30,0) --  (30,100);
            
            \node [above] at (15, 114) {\scriptsize 12.5\%};
            \node [above] at (15, 102) {\scriptsize 14\%};
            
            \draw [pattern=north east lines, draw=black, pattern color=cyan, blend mode=multiply] (0, 114) -- (0, 126.5) -- (30, 126.5) -- (30, 114) -- (0, 114);
            \draw [pattern=north east lines, draw=black, pattern color=cyan, blend mode=multiply] (0, 100) -- (0, 114) -- (30, 114) -- (30, 100);
            \draw [] (0, 0) -- (0, 100) -- (30, 100) -- (30, 0) -- (0, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{.05\textwidth}  % <--- space %\pause
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
 \textbf{Explanation}
 \begin{itemize}
     \item {\footnotesize point one}
     \item {\footnotesize point two }
 \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing a `figure` environment without a caption does in beamer is to center the content. If you don't want your image centred, I would not warp it in a `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
\textbf{Stuff}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.045]
            \node [right] at (34, 50) {\scriptsize stuff 1};
            \node [right] at (34, 107) {\scriptsize  stuff 2};
            \node [right] at (34, 120) {\scriptsize stuff 3};
            
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (30,114) --  (30,126.5);
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (30,100) --  (30,114);
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (30,0) --  (30,100);
            
            \node [above] at (15, 114) {\scriptsize 12.5\%};
            \node [above] at (15, 102) {\scriptsize 14\%};
            
            \draw [pattern=north east lines, draw=black, pattern color=cyan, blend mode=multiply] (0, 114) -- (0, 126.5) -- (30, 126.5) -- (30, 114) -- (0, 114);
            \draw [pattern=north east lines, draw=black, pattern color=cyan, blend mode=multiply] (0, 100) -- (0, 114) -- (30, 114) -- (30, 100);
            \draw [] (0, 0) -- (0, 100) -- (30, 100) -- (30, 0) -- (0, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
 \textbf{Explanation}
 \begin{itemize}
     \item {\footnotesize point one}
     \item {\footnotesize point two }
 \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can push the whole figure left using `\flushleft`. Updated code below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\textbf{Stuff}
    \begin{figure}\flushleft
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.045]
            \node [right] at (34, 50) {\scriptsize stuff 1};
            \node [right] at (34, 107) {\scriptsize  stuff 2};
            \node [right] at (34, 120) {\scriptsize stuff 3};
            
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (30,114) --  (30,126.5);
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (30,100) --  (30,114);
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=6pt,mirror}] (30,0) --  (30,100);
            
            \node [above] at (15, 114) {\scriptsize 12.5\%};
            \node [above] at (15, 102) {\scriptsize 14\%};
            
            \draw [pattern=north east lines, draw=black, pattern color=cyan, blend mode=multiply] (0, 114) -- (0, 126.5) -- (30, 126.5) -- (30, 114) -- (0, 114);
            \draw [pattern=north east lines, draw=black, pattern color=cyan, blend mode=multiply] (0, 100) -- (0, 114) -- (30, 114) -- (30, 100);
            \draw [] (0, 0) -- (0, 100) -- (30, 100) -- (30, 0) -- (0, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}\hspace{.05\textwidth}  % <--- space %\pause
 \begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
 \textbf{Explanation}
 \begin{itemize}
     \item {\footnotesize point one}
     \item {\footnotesize point two }
 \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```